# Different ClinVar classifications/SNPs are linked to the same rsid

Tags: r, snp, wgs, entrez, rsid

I am using R to extract ClinVar classification of SNPs using rsid. Here's an example of my workflow:

Patient data:

| Sample | Func | Gene | Codon_Change | dbSNPv151_GRCh38 | Chr | Start | End | Ref | Obs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | missense_variant | SPINK5 | Cga/Gga | rs199757347 | chr5 | 148091214 | 148091214 | C | G |

With this rsid rs199757347, [two ClinVar classifications](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/clinvar/?term=rs199757347) were found with different codon changes, one is C > G (Uncertain significance, missense variant) and the other one C > T (Pathogenic, nonsense variant).

With the `rentrez` package in R, I can extract both ClinVar classifications:

```r
library(XML)
library(rentrez)

extract_from_esummary(
  entrez_summary(db = "clinvar", 
                 id = entrez_search(db = "clinvar", term = "rs199757347")$ids, 
                 rettype='xml', 
                 parsed = F), 
  "germline_classification"
  )

               968176                               
description    "Uncertain significance"             
last_evaluated "2022/01/01 00:00"                   
review_status  "criteria provided, single submitter"
trait_set      data.frame,2                         
               351517                                                
description    "Pathogenic"                                          
last_evaluated "2019/01/01 00:00"                                    
review_status  "criteria provided, multiple submitters, no conflicts"
trait_set      data.frame,2
```

However, only the classification "Uncertain significance" is relevant to my sample, how can I incorporate the alternative alleles in querying ClinVar with rsid? Or do you have a better way to query ClinVar with my sample data?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use rsIDs? The problem isn't clinvar here, it is that the rsID describes two variants.

Comment: @terdon, Yes I understand, that's why I wish to "incorporate" the info of ALT allele in the search. And based on my sample data, I think the most useful info for querying ClinVar is the rsID. Do you have other recommendations on querying ClinVar if I don't use rsID? Thank you!

Comment: I am afraid not. I am spoiled, the company I work for has a [really good API](https://landing.varsome.com/varsome-api) and that's what I use, but it isn't a free product so any answer I post using it would only be helpful to our clients :/ However, my guess is that you should be able to get the nt change if you don't restrict the output to `germline_classification` only, so then you should be able to parse that to get what you need. Alternatively, if you can convert the rsIDs to HGVS notation (i.e. `NM_006846.4(SPINK5):c.652C>G` in your case), you can query using that.